# Is there a reason why I cannot return inside of a While loop?

Tags: java, while-loop

I am working on a method in my program which has to return the value purchaseMethod. The while loop needs to run until "Q" is input into the console. The issue I am having is that I cannot return while in a while loop. Is there any way around this? Possibly making an array or for loop? If the return statement is necessary to be outside of the while-loop, how would I keep the values to total for the purchaseAmount.

```
public static int getShoppingList(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int eight = 8;
    int hat = 32;
    int patch = 2;
    int sword = 20;
    int map = 100;
    int shirt = 150;
    int quanEight = 0;
    int quanHat = 0;
    int quanPatch = 0;
    int quanSword = 0;
    int quanMap = 0;
    int quanShirt = 0;
    int count = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter Item Code, ? or Q: ");
    String code = input.next();
    // Convert input into character
    char ch = code.charAt(0);
    // Convert string into uppercase
    ch = Character.toUpperCase(ch);
    // Calculate total 

    while (count != 0){
        int purchaseAmount = ( quanEight * eight) + ( quanHat * hat) + ( quanPatch * patch) + ( quanSword * sword) + ( quanShirt * shirt) + ( quanMap * map);
        if (ch == '?'){
            System.out.println("Valid Item codes are: 8 I H M S T.");
            System.out.println("Q to quit.");
        }
        else if (ch == '8'){
            quanEight ++; 

        }
        else if (ch == 'I'){
            quanHat++;
        }
        else if (ch == 'H'){
            quanPatch++;
        }    
        else if (ch == 'M'){
            quanMap++;
        }
        else if (ch == 'S'){
            quanSword++;
        }
        else if (ch == 'T'){
            quanShirt++;
        }     
        else if (ch == 'Q'){
            count++;
            System.out.println("Pirate Trading Post");
            System.out.println(quanEight + " Genuine Piece Of Eight\n " + quanHat + " Pirate Hat\n " + quanPatch + 
                " Eye Patch\n " + quanSword + " Sword\n " + quanMap + " Treasure Map\n " + quanShirt + " T-Shirt\n ");
            System.out.println("Total: " + purchaseAmount + " bits");
            return purchaseAmount;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It's perfectly fine to return from within a while loop- however the problem is that you don't return outside the while loop as well- a non-void method **always** has to return a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If with the **return** command you intend to return the **purchaseAmount** to the caller of **getShoppingList()** method, I suggest you moving the **return** to the end of the method and putting a **break** in its while instead of purchaseAmount. Like this:

```
while (count != 0){    
   // your stuff
   if (...) {
      // ...
   } else if (ch == 'Q'){
      // ...
      break;
   }
}
return purchaseAmount;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is a compile problem with this:

```
        int count = 0;

        while (count != 0){    // count **IS** 0, does not enter
            // your stuff
        }

        // no return
```